# MapField is not displayed in Django Rest Framework Mongoengine

Tags: django, mongodb, mongoengine, restframeworkmongoengine

I have a model with following attributes.

```
class File(DynamicDocument):
    country = fields.StringField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    languages = fields.MapField(fields.MapField(
        fields.EmbeddedDocumentField(AudioImage)))
```

I am trying to use  Django Rest Framework Mongoengine as follows:

```
from rest_framework_mongoengine.serializers import DocumentSerializer

class TestSerializer(DocumentSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = File
```

It simply gives the following output:

[image]

But I wanted it to address the tree like structure with all the fields from AudioImage class as well.
Did I miss anything? or There is another way for MapField ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sijan, is it correct that you want your `File` documents to have the following structure:

```
{
    "country": "UK",
    "languages": {
        "hindi": AudioImageJSON,
        "russian": AudioImageJSON,
        "cockney": AudioImageJSON
    }
}
```

where the structure of AudioImageJSON is described by corresponding EmbeddedDocument?

In that case, your DocumentSerializer is correct and your specify your model as follows:

```
class AudioImage(EmbeddedDocument):
    content = fields.FileField()

class File(DynamicDocument):
    country = fields.StringField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    languages = fields.MapField(fields.EmbeddedDocumentField(AudioImage))
```

Note that Browsable API won't be able to display nested form inputs for EmbeddedDocument fields. But you may still use raw data view.